# I want to be able to use .toggle() but binded to the keydown element - jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, toggle

I've seen thejQElement.toggle(fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4)  would do the trick in case I wanted to click the element. I want it to sequencially fire the events on the tab keydown event.

Thanks

Comment: you might have to roll your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trigger [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) by triggering a [`click` event](http://api.jquery.com/click/), so just trigger that in a [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event, like this:

```
jQElement.keydown(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (keyCode == 9) $(this).click(); //tab key only
});
```

Alternatively, just use this same `keyCode` check and write your own `.tabToggle()` function, it wouldn't be difficult if you [look at the source for `.toggle()`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L904).

[You can view a quick `.tabToggle()` demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtkVm/1/), adjust if needed, but the concept's the same as `.toggle()` already does internally.

Comment: You are missing `e` in function parameter.

Comment: @Sarfraz Ahmed: Fixed, adding a tabToggle method in a minute in case someone's curious